# Как очистить csv базу от линий с пропусками?

Tags: python, база-данных, csv

Существует такая база данных, предположим, database.csv:

[image: база данных]

Необходимо удалить в ней все строки, где отсутствует эмейл, как на 7 строчке.
С именем и фамилией. Записать чистую базу в новый файл.

Пробовал разбираться с csv.DictWriter, но безрезультатно.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то на данном форуме принято сначала демонстрировать свои попытки решения вопроса, а уж потом просить помощи. Тогда проще указывать в вашем коде, где и какие ошибки вы допустили.
Поскольку вы новичек -  за это надеюсь в первый раз не забанят.  Но вот писать за вас код как-то лень. Поэтому рассказываю, как и вы, без кода.

1. Читаете свой с csv файл в Pandas DataFrame.
2. В этом датафрейме удаляете строки, содержащие пропуски данных. Для этого используют метод

> dropna()

Другой вариант:

> df[df['....'].notna()]

3. Полученный в результате датафрейм записывают в файл.

Нюансы, которые могут возникнуть ввиду тех особенностей вашего кода или данных, которые вы от нас скрыли, не показав скрипт, придется в таком случае вам решать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html):

```python
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

(pd.read_csv("database.csv", sep=",")
   .dropna(subset=["email"])
   .to_csv("result.csv", index=False))
```